# How to search for a particular row, column value and then return the row number?

Tags: excel

I'm having an trouble making an excel formula at the moment which would get first search for the row, column value and then return the row number from which I can get the another column value in the same row.

Right now, I've made this function. `=INDEX('Rent'!$D$2:$D$73, MATCH(0, ($B$6='Rent'!$B$2:$B$73)*($C$7='Rent'!$A$2:$A$73),0))`

Here rent is another sheet, and first i'm searching for the particular value like $B$6 here in first MATCH function by searching for the value in 'Rent' sheet's column and then same for next check. The resulting match would contain bow `$B$6` and similarly `$C$7` in the same row and then I want to return the value of another column value in the same row.

Please, let me know how can I do this. I've been stuck at this a long time.

The rent sheet looks like this:

[image: The Sample Data]

Comment: Can you add some sample data to make this clearer? I think I know what you're getting at but it would make this easier to answer.

Comment: @BigBen I just added the sample rent sheet data which i want to lookup and rent the matching last column for the count.

Comment: Can you just use `SUMIFS` for this?

Comment: @BigBen i tried using that, how do you think i can use that? thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the values in $B$6 and $C$7?

Comment: $B$6 has glen and $C$7 has Studio-HF

Comment: and then the matching Count column would return 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data, I think you can just use `SUMIFS` for this:

```
=SUMIFS('Rent'!$D$2:$D$73,'Rent'!$B$2:$B$73,$B$6,'Rent'!$A$2:$A$73,$C$7)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. quick question, what if i also want to compare another condition on the result like if I change the count column to date and want to check if date is greater than a particular date, can i do this =SUMIFS('Rent'!$D$2:$D$73>'15/09/2019','Rent'!$B$2:$B$73,$B$6,'Rent'!$A$2:$A$73,$C$7)

Comment: I'm not sure you'd use SUMIFS on a date. Maybe COUNTIFS. What do you want to return?

Comment: i want to return all dates greater than 15/09/2019 from a column with the same two previous conditions. 'Rent'!$B$2:$B$73=$B$6,'Rent'!$A$2:$A$73=$C$7 Do you think Countifs would work? How?

Comment: So you want a list of dates? Maybe post a new question with revised sample data.

Comment: i figured this one out, thanks for your help but got into another error and added a question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389240/how-to-use-year-function-inside-the-countif-in-excel-formula