# How to use year function inside the Countif in excel formula?

Tags: excel

I'm having an trouble making an excel formula at the moment which would first search for the value by getting the year from the dates and then search another value from the sheet. Finally return the count.

Please, let me know how can I do this. I've been stuck at this a long time.

Right now i'm using this formula.

```
=COUNTIFS('Inc'!$F$2:$F$984,"YEAR('Incg'!$F$2:$F$984)=2017",'Incident Log'!$J$2:$J$984,$F9)`
```

Comment: Will you please provide a small sample of the table? So we can understand better what you need. What is the problem which you encounter? You get some error? Count is wrong?

Comment: @virolino I added the sample data. please check

Comment: the problem is it returns zero but shouldn't return zero, $F9 contains the value Noise and behaviour @virolino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `YEAR()` as an argument to `COUNTIFS` in this case, because its output is the numerical value 2017 whereas the value you want to use for your comparison is 42736, the internal representation of this year. A possible workaround is:

```
=COUNTIFS('Incident Log'!$F$2:$F$984,">="&DATE(2017,1,1),'Incident Log'!$F$2:$F$984,"<"&DATE(2018,1,1), ...)
```

This extracts the numerical date values of January 1 2017 and 2018, and checks whether each value lies between those dates.

If you do want to use `YEAR()` then you can use it with `SUMPRODUCT`, which was the usual way of solving problems like this before `COUNTIFS` became available.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR('Incident Log'!$F$2:$F$984)=2017),--('Incident Log'!$J$2:$J$984=$F9))
```